# Form Variable Becomes Part of Link to Web Page

Tags: asp.net, forms

We are hosting a PURL site and the variable is at the end: http://mywebpage.com/first.last

Now the client wants a static web page where you go and enter a first and last, then on submit it goes to out PURL site.

Tried this with straight html but it's not going to work. On to ASP.

New to ASP and I'm trying to have a form that has 2 fields, first, last in a link. Here is the form concept:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="1">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first" id="first" />
    <label for="2">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="last" id="last" />
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="3" id="3" onclick="window.open('http://mywebpage.com/first=val1&.&last=val2')"/>
  </p>
</form>
```

Any help to put me on the right tracks would be extremely welcome at this point.

Thank you,
Ed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="GET" action="http://mywebpage.com/" >
```

Then do a normal submit without `onclick` and `window.open`.

`action` will submit form to that URL, and `method="GET"` will pass form parameters in a query string.